# How to read xls file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iformfile, exceldatareader

Net core API. I am trying to read xls file using ExcelDataReader. In ExcelDataReader I do not want to pass file path but I want to pass stream. I tried below

```
 [HttpPost("import")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Import(IFormFile formFile)
 {
   excelReader.IExcelDataReader reader;

            if (formFile == null || formFile.Length <= 0)
            {
                return  Ok("formfile is empty");
            }
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
            }
 }
```

When I execute I get exception

> No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a
> custom encoding, see the documentation for the
> Encoding.RegisterProvider method.

I am not sure what would be the root cause of the issue? Can someone help me here to fix the issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a dependency to the package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages and register the encoding by adding this line to your code:

```
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

See [this note on github](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader#important-note-on-net-core)

Answer (score 1):

**You can read both xls and xlsx.**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Import(IFormFile formFile)
        {
            excelReader.IExcelDataReader reader;
            if (formFile == null || formFile.Length <= 0)
            {
                return Ok("formfile is empty");
            }
            var path = Path.GetExtension(formFile.FileName);
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                if (path.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
                }
                if (path.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                }
            }
        }
```